# Pause on hover of carousel doesn't work in FireFox

Tags: firefox, hover, carousel

I've built a custom bootstrap carousel, but cannot seem to get the hover effect to work in FireFox (works fine in Safari & Chrome). Has anyone run into this before? If so, what's the solution?

I'm using data-pause="hover".

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that I am seeing as well.  Here is what im doing until this bug is addressed

```
    $('.carousel').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel("pause");
    })

    $('.carousel').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel("cycle");
    })
```